# 'JobSerializer' object has no attribute 'email' what i am missing?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

serializers.py

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, 
    #                         use_url=True)
    # applicant = serializers.ForeignKe
    applicant = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_username_from_user")
    company_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_company_name_from_user")
    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = ['company_name', 'email',  'title', 'desc', 'image', 'price',  'category', 'applicant']
        # extra_kwargs = {"email": {"required": False}}




    def get_username_from_user(self, jobs):
        email = jobs.user.email
        return email

    def get_company_name_from_user(self, jobs):
        company_name = jobs.user.company_name
        return company_name
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def api_detail_jobs_view(request, id):
    try:
        jobs = Jobs.objects.get(id=id)
    except Jobs.DoesNotExist:
        data = {}
        data['response'] = "Job does not exist"
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    
    if request.method == "GET":

        serializer = JobSerializer(jobs)
        user = request.user
        if user == serializer.email:
            data = {}
            auth_show = serializer
            data['title'] = auth_show.title 
            data['applicant'] = auth_show.applicant
            return Response(data)
        else:
            no_auth_show = serializer
            data = {}
            data['title'] = no_auth_show.title
            return Response(data)
```

here is serializers.py in which 'email' is included. i know i am missing something very   clear but it took hours to realise :) so any help will be appriciated
i am trying to show 'applicants' only to users who owns the 'job' but i can't pass 'email' from serializer in to the view. I can't pass any attribute from serializer in to data dict.

Comment: sorry for             data['desc'] = auth_show.applicant
 this line. must be:  data['applicant'] = auth_show.applicant

Comment: Zurab, you can and should just edit your post :)

Comment: @NixonSparrow Done sir:) My first question on stack overflow. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation of DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects), after serializing an object you can access its fields via the `data` attribute. So it would look like `serializer.data['email']`.

And one extra tip, consider using the Django shortcut [get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of that `try/except` block. Good luck!